# piechart - how to remove x labels on piechart and show ite on beside of it?

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

[I want show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKJg.png)I am working on pie chart i am using MP Android Chart library. now, problem is i don't want to show label names on pie chart and i want to show all label names beside pies chart.

```
           public  void  setPieChart()
{
    PieChart pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);
    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    ArrayList<Entry> yvalues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    yvalues.add(new Entry(8f, 0));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(15f, 1));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(12f, 2));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(25f, 3));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(23f, 4));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(17f, 5));

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "");
   // PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yValues, "");
    for (Entry pieEntry : yvalues){
        if(pieEntry.getVal() < 10)
        {
            pieEntry.setXIndex(0);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    xVals.add("January");
    xVals.add("February");
    xVals.add("March");
    xVals.add("April");
    xVals.add("May");
    xVals.add("June");
    xVals.add("January");
    xVals.add("February");
    xVals.add("March");
    xVals.add("April");
    xVals.add("May");
    xVals.add("June");

    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    pieChart.setData(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code I think it will help to show lable beside pies chart

```
        Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
        legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART_CENTER);
        legend.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        legend.setYEntrySpace(5f);
        legend.setYOffset(0f);
```

Comment: thank you and one more is can i show values besides the piechart now its shwing under it and on click of this can i show the value like web application

Comment: happy to help... @Mikey so please verify the answer

Comment: thank you @vikas singh one more is that i have 20 xvalues i want two show in two vertical lines in android

Answer (score 0):

try this solution if you need the x values outside

```
PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys,"");
pieDataSet.setXValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
pieChart.setData(pieData);
```

Comment: no i want to show besides it now its showing under pie chart